# Migration to a new version of Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm having a problem with upgrading to a new version of Spring.
I have a configuration class WebSecurityConfig.
I used to inherit it from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but in new versions of Spring they removed it. Can you please tell me how I can rewrite this class for the new version of Spring?
I want to rewrite this for Spring version 3.1.2

```
package ua.com.alevel.config.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(@Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl") UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/user/getActualUser").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/user/loginUser").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/user/logoutUser", "POST"))
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(false)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/user/loginUser");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

    @Bean
    protected DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this blog article: [Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change from

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
// What else... 
}
```

to

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

Same problem happens to me a few months ago, I didnt remember exactly where found this solution. I just paste the solution I did in my project.